# How i draw 3textbox in in <td>

Tags: html

![example of textbox i want![][1]][1]

EXAPMLE OF textbox

hi to all
 i have some problem with Table
when i create  tage
i want like example below.
i have some problem
1. when i enter 
CNIC-NO
--

they cannot dispplay same line

Note. i have only 2 coloumns in my table.
plz tell me how i draw this text box like example attached below.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulpZm.png "table

---

"

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do this

```
<td>
        <input type="text" style="display: inline-block" />
        <input type="text" style="display: inline-block" />
        <input type="text" style="display: inline-block" />
    </td>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but bro these fields not a same line i want enter CNIC#: 33100 - 2323232323 - 5 three textbox in one <td> same line plz tell me